# How to use the Tab Key to Switch Between Buttons in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have several buttons in my stack. I am looking for the code of Tab Key to Switch Between Buttons in my stack.Is it possible to Tab Key to Switch Between all control in my stack

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the standard. If the property **traversalOn** of some controls is true, you can switch between those controls using tab.
TraversalOn is described also like "focus with keyboard" on the property inspector panel.